# In Xamarin.Android, how to ensure SoftInput AdjustResize works correctly on Keyboard's up/down event?

Tags: android, android-layout, xamarin, xamarin.android, mvvmcross

What we need to accomplish:

- As a user I want to see a picture with the maximum size on the screen, from the screen bottom to the header's bottom
- When the keyboard goes up or down, the picture should resize itself so it is always fully visible using the maximum space.

[image]

I've accomplished that in a mini project by following these steps:

1 - Add following attribute in Android.manifest.xml **application property:**

```
android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize"
```

2 - Adding this line of code in the **MainActivity OnCreate** event handler:

```
Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
```

3 - using this layout property in the **ImageView** object:

```
android:layout_weight="1"
```

That works fine in a mini project but when I port that code to our real project it does not work. When the keyboard prompts, the picture and the header seems to be scrolled up.

[image]

The image is not resized, the picture is not fully visible and the header is not visible at all.

The main difference in the real project is that it uses MVVMCross and there is no MainActivity class. There is a MainApplication class which is declared as:

```
public class MainApplication : MvxAndroidApplication<Setup, App>
```

I can't add the Window.SetSoftInputMode there because it says: "CS0120: An object reference is required for the non-static field, method, or property 'Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput)'""

So I tried using it in the View Activity as follows:

```
[Activity(Label = "PhotoCaptionView", WindowSoftInputMode = SoftInput.AdjustResize, ScreenOrientation = ScreenOrientation.Portrait, Theme = "@style/IM.Theme.Main", LaunchMode = LaunchMode.SingleTask)]
public class EditPostView : BaseIMActivity<EditPostViewModel> 
protected override void OnCreate(Bundle bundle)
{
    Window.SetSoftInputMode(SoftInput.AdjustResize);
    base.OnCreate(bundle);
}
```

Notice that I am setting SoftInput.AdjustResize in two places, as a decorator and also inline.

I also added the property in the Android manifest but nothing seems to make AdjustResize work.
I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was a style.xml file that had this property set:

```
<item name="android:windowFullscreen">true</item>
```